# Disable two QPushButton when another is checked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have 3 `QpushButton` (x,y,z) in my program. I have to set 2 buttons (y,z) to be disabled while another QpushButton (x) is in Checkable mode.
While X in Checkable mode others should be disabled. 
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance..

My code:

```
    self.btn_mpgX.setCheckable(True)
    self.btn_mpgY.setEnabled(False);
    self.btn_mpgZ.setEnabled(False);
    self.btn_mpgX.toggled.connect(self.btn_mpgXuncheckable)

def btn_mpgXuncheckable(self):
    self.btn_mpgY.setEnabled(True);
    self.btn_mpgZ.setEnabled(True);
    self.btn_mpgX.toggled.connect(self.initUI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expect behaviour: one checkable `QPushButton` (X) that disables/enables two regular `QPushButton` (Y and Z) when checked/unchecked (correct me if I'm wrong)

As in your sample code, you can use the signal `toggled(bool checked)`. The boolean allows you to know if the button is checked or unchecked, and you can enabled/disabled the other buttons accordingly.

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.buttonX=QtGui.QPushButton("X")
        self.buttonY=QtGui.QPushButton("Y")
        self.buttonZ=QtGui.QPushButton("Z")

        self.buttonX.setCheckable(True)
        self.buttonX.toggled.connect(self.on_check_X)

        #layout
        hbox=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.buttonX)
        hbox.addWidget(self.buttonY)
        hbox.addWidget(self.buttonZ)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def on_check_X(self,is_toggle):
        if is_toggle:
            self.buttonY.setEnabled(False)
            self.buttonZ.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.buttonY.setEnabled(True)
            self.buttonZ.setEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win= MyWidget()
    win.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```